# what's the best instance size selection for azure vm roles?

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud

I currently have 2 **ExtraSmall** webroles(MVC4) running on Azure cloud services(windows server 2012).I logged into the RDP and checked is's resources usage by task manager, found out that the memory usage is very high, one is about 92% used and only 56Mb free memory left, another is 86% has 150Mb free memory left. The website is very slow, is it possible the low performance's caused by the low memory?Do you think it's better upgrade the VM size to Small or larger?

Thx a lot

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Comment: Agreed (even though I posted an answer). Can this be moved to ServerFault, where it's more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, only you can determine best instance size. From Small (1 core, 1.75GB, 100Mbps NIC) to Extra Large (8 core, 14GB, 800Mbps NIC), machines scale in a straightforward way, and you should pick the smallest instance size that can properly and efficiently run your app, and then scale out/in as necessary. The A6/A7 machines are significantly larger (4 core, 28GB, 1000Mbps NIC, 8 core, 56GB, 2000Mbps NIC), and the Extra Small is very limited (shared core, 768MB, 5Mbps NIC). Extra Small instances may have issues running certain workloads.

So: You may be having issues related to the XS resource limitations for your particular app. You should do some empirical testing on Small through Extra Large to see where low-volume app experiences work fine, and then pick that size, using multiple instances to handle heavier load.

When picking the size, you'll probably reach a bottleneck with a specific resource (CPU, RAM, network), and you'll need to pick based on that. For example, if you really need 6GB RAM, you're now looking at a Large, even if you're barely utilizing CPU.

More details on instances sizes, [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/cloud-services/).

Comment: thanks David, that's really helpful to me.But just one more question, multiple-instances is only working on a fault domain or on both fault and load balancing?

Comment: Both. With multiple instances, the endpoints will be load-balanced across your instances.

Answer (score 0):

It's always easy to scale up to the Small first then go to Large.  You are going to be doubling your memory with a small at 1.75 GB.  Plus on the Extra Small you are using Shared CPU Cores on a Small you don't share the cores.

Going to a Large with 7 GB of memory would be overkill, I think.

Comment: *Going to a Large with 7 GB of memory would be overkill...* Really there's no way to determine that without empirical testing.